# Equivariant characteristic classes on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, equivariant-cohomology

Let $T=(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ act on $\mathbb{P}^n$ torically by
$$t.[x_0:\dots:x_n]=[x_0\;:\;t_1x_1\;:\;\ldots \;:\;t_nx_n]$$

I would like to know an expression for

1. the equivariant Chern character $\mathrm{ch}^T(\chi\cdot\mathcal{O}(d))$, where $\chi\cdot\mathcal{O}(d)$ is the equivariant line bundle isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(d)$ and given by the character $\chi:T\to \mathbb{C}^*$, and
2. the equivariant Todd genus $\mathrm{Td}^T(\mathbb{P}^n)$ .

In alternative to 1., I'd be happy with $\mathrm{ch}^T(\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}_Z)$ where $\mathcal{I}_Z$ is the ideal sheaf of a closed invariant subscheme $Z\subset\mathbb{P}^n$. Also, take $n=2$ if you want.

The more concrete and explicit, the better...

Comment: If you denote by $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in \text{CH}_T^*(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}))$ the first Chern classes of the characters $\chi_i$ with $\chi_i(t)=t_i$, then the equivariant Chow ring of $T$ is $A=\mathbb{Z}[\lambda_1,\lambda_1^{-1},\dots,\lambda_n,\lambda_n^{-1}]$.  If we take $\mathcal{O}(1)$ with the $T$-linearization that you have specified above, then denoting by $\zeta$ the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in $\text{CH}_T^*(\mathbb{P}^n)$, this Chow ring is isomorphic to $A[\zeta]/\langle \zeta(\zeta-\lambda_1)\cdots (\zeta-\lambda_n) \rangle$ . . .

Comment: . . . The Chern character of $\chi\cdot \mathcal{O}(d)$ is $e^{\chi + d\zeta}$.  Using the equivariant Euler sequence, the equivariant Todd class of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$ equals the product over $i=0,1,\dots,n$ of the Todd class of $\lambda_i^\vee\cdot \mathcal{O}(1)$ (taking $\lambda_0$ to be $1$).  Each of these equals $(\zeta-\lambda_i)/(1-e^{\lambda_i-\zeta})$.

Comment: Actually, now I think that $A$ is just the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[\lambda_1,\lambda_1^{-1},\dots,\lambda_n,\lambda_n^{-1}]$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: why the ring with the $\lambda_i$'s and not with the $\lambda_i^{\pm}$? I thought the first version was correct, at least if $A$ has to be isomorphic to the representation ring $R(T)$ of $T$? (which is, the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{X}^*(T)]$ of the character lattice $\mathrm{X}^*(T)$ of $T$)

Comment: @Qfwq The representation ring $R(T)$ of $T$ should be the $K$-ring, not the Chow ring.  For smooth separated schemes, the Chern character gives an isomorphism between the two rings (after passing to rational coefficients), but not for Artin stacks.  The Totaro / Edidin-Graham equivariant Chow ring of $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the limit of the Chow rings of the quotients $(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{G}_m = \mathbb{P}^n$. So $\text{CH}_{\mathbb{G}_m}^*(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}))$ equals $\mathbb{Z}[\lambda]$, and $A$ equals $\mathbb{Z}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$ by taking tensor products.

Comment: @JasonStarr: thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just posting my comments as an answer.  Denote by $A$ the equivariant Chow ring $\text{CH}^*_T(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}))$.  For $i=1,\dots,n$, denote by $\lambda_i\in A^1$ the first Chern class of the character $\chi_i$ with $\chi_i(t) = t_i$.  Denote by $\lambda_0$ the class $0$, i.e., the first Chern class of the constant character.  Then $A$ is the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$.

Denote by $B$ the equivariant Chow ring $\text{CH}^*_T(\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}})$ as an $A$-algebra.
Give $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ the unique $T$-linearization so that the associated action of $T$ on $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}},\mathcal{O}(1)) = \text{span}(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the specified action.  Denote by $\zeta\in B^1$ the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ with this $T$-linearization.  Then $B$ equals $A[\zeta]/\langle (\zeta-\lambda_0)(\zeta-\lambda_1)\cdots (\zeta-\lambda_n) \rangle$.

The given $T$-linearization of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ induces a $T$-linearization of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ that has first Chern class $d\zeta$.  Thus, the first Chern class of $\chi\cdot \mathcal{O}(d)$ equals $\chi + d\zeta$.  Therefore the Chern character of $\chi\cdot \mathcal{O}(d)$ equals $e^{\chi + d\zeta}$.

Similarly, the Todd class of the tangent sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ with its intrinsic $T$-linearization equals
$$ \text{Td}(\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}) = \prod_{i=0}^n \frac{\zeta-\lambda_i}{1-e^{\lambda_i-\zeta}}.$$